# Using joint angles to animate a character

Tags: python, scripting, animation

I work on modeling of human locomotion, I have a physical model of walking that runs on a gazebo like software (ODE based). I extracted the joint angles of a walking cycle in a file and want to use that to animate a body in blender.

I have an already rigged model in blender and I would like to animate the model using the joint angles extracted from my model. I need some hints, because I am new to blender and don't know where to start. I guess it should be possible to directly access the armature from python for example and specify the orientation of each joint. Is that possible ? Is there any tool or example showing that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done, no I don't know any existing examples. The best I can think of is the [bvh import script](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_anim_bvh/) or the [Motion Capture tools](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/mocap/) addon.

Blender's [python api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/) is available online but you may find it easier to use the autocomplete feature in the python console.

As a hint to get started -

```
bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones["head"].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'

bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['head'].rotation_euler[0] = 32

bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['head'].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame = 10)
```

I can't say if this is the best or correct way to pose armatures by script.